# How can I handicap the `rm` command?

Tags: rm

I have a really bad history of `rm`ing file then regretting it. I've since created a `trash` command that I'm trying to use more.

However, I still have a lot of muscle memory built around `rm`. Is there any way I could handicap the `rm` command? Maybe force it to give me a confirmation or just make it unusable?

Comment: Once you hit peak regret, your behaviour will start to reflect that; trying to "handicap `rm`" is just routing around the real issue.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a good strategy, and specially to users with admin privileges, is aliasing the rm command to rm -i, that requires confirmation.

place it on your .bashrc

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Comment: `--preserve-root` is the default, therefore redundant.

Comment: There is a downside to doing this—you'll get in the habit of depending on `rm` asking if you're sure. Then when you log in to some other system, you'll be in for a surprise! So I really wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I have been using this for ages. Good for our sysiops too. People often in a while make mistakes, and this gives them one last chance to back out.

Answer (score 2):

Making `rm` prompt for confirmation (as in [Rui F Ribeiro's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244447/977)) will get you in the habit of depending on that. Then should you ever log in to a different system, you'll be in for an unwelcome surprise.

Instead, I'd suggest retraining yourself—two approaches come to mind:

One, which you suggested, is to make `rm` just not work. That's fairly easy, `alias rm=~/bin/dont-use-rm` (and then, optionally, create that script with an echo reminding you and an `exit 1`).

The second is to train yourself to always type `rm -i`. You could make yourself: again `alias rm=~/bin/force-rm-i`, and have that be a shell script along the lines of:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

if [ '-i' != "$1" ]; then
    # you could use getopt, etc. for better command-line parsing, but that
    # is much more work.
    echo -e "\aIgnoring your command because you forgot to use 'rm -i'."
    exit 1
else
    exec rm "$@"
fi
```

(Note: "echo -e" may not be supported by all shells; feel free to use `/bin/bash` up top if your `/bin/sh` does not.)

Use aliases for this because you can easily set those up to only affect interactive shells—you don't want to break "rm" in shell scripts.

Comment: I have dealt with all kind of Unixes...it does not makes much a difference wether you have this or not for me, but it is a lifesaver for our system operators.

Comment: I'd make `force-rm-i` a function, that way the `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/… remains self-contained.